# Show custom post archive when custom post not specified

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have a custom post type called `produce` set up in WordPress and a custom taxonomy called `produce_category`.

The URL format for posts in this custom post type is in this format `http://mywebsite/produce/%produce_category%/%postname%/`. Of course `%produce_category%` and `%postname%` get substituted accordingly, a working example url would be `http://mywebsite/produce/fruits-and-vegetables/avocado`.

What I would like to do is show the produce_category custom taxonomy archive if a user visits `http://mywebsite/produce/%produce_category%`, without specifying post name at the end, e.g `http://mywebsite/produce/fruits-and-vegetables` to show all produce in fruits-and-vegetables produce_category.

Besides that when a user visits `http://mywebsite/produce/` I would like to show all the produce archive. EDIT: I have this working now.

I know how to create the archive pages totally fine and have no problem with that. I am stuck at creating permalinks. When I visit `http://mywebsite/produce/%produce_category%` I get a 404 error.

I'm looking for advise on the best way to implement this. Currently I am using **Custom Post Type Permalinks** and **CPTUI**.

The CPTUI custom taxonomy settings interface does not allow me to have a blank in the custom rewrite slug. It defaults to the custom taxonomy slug, `produce_category`, when I don't fill in anything. 
[image]

This gives the front-side produce_category taxonomy archive url as `http://mywebsite/produce/produce_category/%produce_category%/` e.g. `http://mywebsite/produce/produce_category/fish-and-seafood/` when what I want for the archive is `http://mywebsite/produce/fish-and-seafood/`.

Please help with suggestion on the best way I can achieve the custom taxonomy url.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite the taxonomy url in the .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^produce_category(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

(Not tested)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning I will indicate that the expected structure conflicts with the default for custom post type `produce` posts.

The solution to the problem requires changing the links created for the custom categories and appropriate parsing of new links to display the right posts.

Use the [`pre_term_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_term_link) filter to change links. One of the parameters passed 
is the WP_Term object for which the link is generated. If its taxonomy is `produce_category` then the new `{cpt}/%{taxonomy}%` structure should be returned, 
that is `produce/%produce_category%`.

```
add_filter( 'pre_term_link', 'se355448_pre_term_link', 10, 2 );

function se355448_pre_term_link( $termlink, $term )
{
    if ( ! $term instanceof \WP_Term || $term->taxonomy != 'produce_category' )
        return $termlink;

    return '/produce/%produce_category%';
}
```

Then, for links to be recognized correctly, use the [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function to add the necessary rewrite rules. As already mentioned, your target structure collides with links to custom post type `produce` posts, that's why you need rewrite rules for every term in `produce_category` taxonomy, and they should be **before** CPT `produce` rules.

```
add_action( 'init', 'se355448_rewrite_rules' );

function se355448_rewrite_rules()
{
    $cpt = 'produce';
    $tax = 'produce_category';
    //$terms = ['fruits-and-vegetables', 'fish-and-seafood'];
    $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy'  => $tax,
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'fields'    => 'id=>slug',
    ]);
    if ( is_array($terms) && count($terms) )
    {
        foreach( $terms as $slug )
        {
            add_rewrite_rule(
                "{$cpt}/{$slug}(?:/page/([0-9]+))?/?$",
                "index.php?{$tax}={$slug}&taxonomy={$tax}&post_type={$cpt}&paged=\$matches[1]",
                'top'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Each term needs a rewrite rule, so after adding a new one, deleting it, or changing slug of existing one, rewrite rules need to be refreshed. This can be done by clicking "*Save*" in "*Settings* -> *Permalinks*".

The code below will automatically, using the [`created_{$taxonomy}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy) and [`delete_{$taxonomy}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_taxonomy) action hooks, update rewrite rules **after adding or removing** terms from `produce_category` taxonomy.

```
add_action( 'created_produce_category', 'se355448_refresh_rules', 20);
add_action( 'delete_produce_category',  'se355448_refresh_rules' );

function se355448_refresh_rules()
{
    se355448_rewrite_rules();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```